# jQuery - check URL for anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I made a really simple tab interface using jQuery based on [jQuery minitabs](http://code.google.com/p/minitabs/):

```
$(".tabs .nav").delegate("a", "click", function(){
  var tabs = $(this).closest(".tabs");
  var target = $(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];

  $(".nav a", tabs).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $("input.active-tab", tabs).val(target);

  //hide the tabs that doesn't match the ID
  $('.tab:not(.'+target+')', tabs).hide();
  $('.tab.'+target, tabs).show();

  return false;
});
```

the markup looks like:

```
  <div class="tabs">

    <input type="hidden" class="active-tab" name="active-tab" value="tab1" />

    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#tab1" class="active">tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab tab1">
    ....
    </div>

    <div class="tab tab2">
    ....
    </div>

    <div class="tab tab3">
    ....
    </div>
  </div>
```

It works fine, but I want to make so the active tab can be set based on the current URL.

for eg. if I paste this URL: `http://site.com/page.php#tab2`, I want the tab2 to appear as active

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is located in `window.location.hash`

you can search `$(".tabs .nav")` for a link that has the same hash and trigger a click on it

Comment: I did it with `if(window.location.hash == $(this).attr('href')) $(this).trigger('click');` thanks :D